# Service is creating new instance of mediaplayer

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer, kotlin

I have a problem with service.

In method onCreate I'm creating media player.
When I'm moving between activities, I'm able to access service smoothly and it keeps the same media player instance. Although, when I leave application (audio from services mediaplayer  is still playing) and then I return to application - I  get new MediaPlayer instance. Audio stream from previous instance is still playing.

I would like to have the access to the same instance of MediaPlayer as preiously to manipulate playing song (pause for example).

Do you know what may be the issue?

```
class PlayerService : Service(), MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, PlayerServiceContract.ServiceContract {

    private val mBinder = PlayerBinder()

    private var mPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

    private var mPresenter: PlayerServiceContract.Presenter? = null

    private var mRecording: Recording? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        mPlayer?.setWakeMode(applicationContext,
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK)
        mPlayer?.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)        
        mPlayer?.setOnPreparedListener(this)
```

Comment: Check whether onDestroy() of the service is called or not.

Comment: If you unbind the service when the activity is gone, then the service can be destroyed when you leave the application. First check that.

Comment: your code is not complete, put your complete class or at least complete function code here.

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

A bound service will be shut down if the service gets unbound for all of its bindings.
A service that is started by `startService()` will be shut down if the service is shut down by calling `stopSelf()` or `stopService()`.

A service that is both called by `startService()` and `bindService()` will be destroyed if  AND stopSelf() or `stopService()`.

> A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In
>   such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as
>   either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with
>   the Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag. Once neither of these situations
>   hold, the service's onDestroy() method is called and the service is
>   effectively terminated. All cleanup (stopping threads, unregistering
>   receivers) should be complete upon returning from onDestroy().
>   - From [Service.Service Lifecycle | Android Developers Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

In your case, when the activities are gone, the service seems to enter the unbound state and may be destroyed.
Maybe you have to call `startService()` in the same service when you start the play, and call `stopSelf()` when you stop the play, so that the service cannot be destroyed while it is playing media.

NOTE: Some say that you have to call `stopSelf()` after unbinding all. Some say that the order of stop and unbind is not relevant. I don't know which is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I actually did not start service by startService but bindService, and this was the root of the problem.